# nodejs zlib inflate error after redis LPOP 'incorrect header check'

Tags: javascript, node.js, compression, zlib

I am compressing a large string with zlib, and pushing the stringified version of the commpressed data it to the redis

After fetching from redis, am trying to decompress it, but i get the error "incorrect header check".

Can anyone tell me what is going wrong here in the below code.

```
let zlib = require('zlib');
let redis = require('redis')
let redisClient = redis.createClient()

let input = new Buffer.from('hello, world 66')
let enc = zlib.deflateSync(input);



console.log("ENCoded, check buffer length here", enc.toString('utf-8'), enc)
console.log("Immediate DEcode", zlib.inflateSync(enc).toString('utf8'))


redisClient.rpush('kilo', enc.toString('utf-8'))

setTimeout(() => {
    redisClient.blpop('kilo', 10, function (err, reply) {
        if(err){
            throw new Error(err.message)
        }
        const inp = new Buffer.from(reply[1], 'utf-8')
        console.log("POPPED :: Check Buffer length here", reply[1], inp)
        console.log(zlib.inflateSync(inp))
    })
}, 800);
```

Thank you.